# SDWebImage 4 - How I can cancel download request ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cocoapods, sdwebimage

In the new version of **SDWebImage** (by CocoaPods ver >= 4.x) `sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad` has deprecated and removed. How I can cancel download request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching, I found [migration guide](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/Docs/SDWebImage-4.0-Migration-guide.md):

> UIImageView (WebCache) moved to UIView (WebCache), UIImageView objects still respond to those methods:
>
> - sd_imageURL
> - **sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad**
> - setShowActivityIndicatorView: renamed to sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView:
> - setIndicatorStyle: renamed to sd_setIndicatorStyle: